# Why GWT browser plugin is not supported in Mozilla Firefox 27 onwards?

Tags: firefox, gwt, firefox-addon

I am not able to run my GWT application due to browser plugin issue. I have tried to find the GWT plugin for Mozilla Firefox browser for the version of 36. Could you please anyone can help me to identify the suitable plugin.

Comment: The plugin is no longer supported, you should look into using Super Dev Mode from now on if possible.

Comment: Thank you very much Bjartr. I got it. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, I am successfully running my gwt application on any of the browser, without installing any browser plugin. If you are using **gwt-2.6.0**, run your application in **Super Server Mode**. That will generate a link related to your application. Place that link in any browser url bar and run it. But it will take some time of compiling the application and then you will get the UI on the browser screen. To install gwt-2.6.0 onwards, your installed JDK should be after 7 version.

Comment: Please note that 2.7 is massively faster to recompile for Super Dev Mode, and the upcoming 2.8 release (available in nightly builds now) will be even faster still.

Comment: Is there any major code changes in 2.7 compare to 2.4? It will really cause any problems when we will upgrade from 2.4 to 2.7?

Comment: while installing gwt plugin through eclipse, by default it is coming as 2.6. How can I specially install even 2.7?

Comment: 2.7 is literally years ahead of 2.4 - all of the fixes in 2.5, 2.5.1, 2.6, etc are missing from 2.4. As for eclipse, make sure you are using the newest version of the eclipse plugin, which does support 2.7 and has specific code in it to run Super Dev Mode.

Comment: Thanks Colin, If any problem I will comeback.

Answer (score 2):

Rationale can be found in the GWT forum: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-web-toolkit/QSEjbhhHB4g/wtI5TYFRevsJ

**TL;DR:** the plugin was using APIs that have been removed in Firefox 27, so it's no longer possible to compile it (and it was required to recompile it for each new version of Firefox).